# Wordpress - unable to set up due to base URL

Tags: wordpress, urls, base-page

I've recently installed CiviCRM onto Wordpress however when trying to complete set up, I keep getting an error stating that the base URL does not match (despite Wordpress doing the installation) - I've checked both the settings on CiviCRM and also Wordpress and the base URLs match (eg https://www.mydomainname.com) - It won't let me proceed with amending anything to complete set up. Any help would be gratefully appreciated!

[image]

It looks like the same issue as [Could not find a valid session key - URL settings correct](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/41362/could-not-find-a-valid-session-key-url-settings-correct) - any help or advice would be gratefully appreciated as CiviCRM is perfect for my voluntary organisation, I just can't get the thing implemented!

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to SE!  Often errors like this relate to a mismatch between www.domain.com vs domain.com or http: vs https:  At what point in the setup process do you get this error?